# Apollo CodeGen can't generate TS types

Tags: apollo

I'm trying to generate some TS types using Apollo CodeGen using json from  an introspection query.

The top of the schema file looks like this (let me know if I can provide other info)

```
{
  "data": {
  "__schema": {
  ...
```

the error I get is this

```
➜  continuum git:(typescript) ✗ apollo client:codegen --target typescript --localSchemaFile="./schema.json"
{ Error: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project": Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }
```

Followed by a LOT of output I can't make sense of. Here's a bit of it:

```
graphql-schema:/schema.graphql?%22%22%22Schema%20for%20types%20that%20can%20be%20active%20or%20inactive%22%22%22%0Ainterface%20ActivatedInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%22%22%22Is%20this%20object%20enabled%3F%22%22%22%0A%20%20active%3A%20Bool!%0A%7D%0A%0A%22%22%22An%20advertisement%22%22%22%0Atype%20Ad%20implements%20CommonInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%22%22%22Aggregate%20data%20for%20the%20campaigns%20field%22%22%22%0A%20%20_campaignStats(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Only%20live%20items%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20onlyLive%3A%20Bool%20%3D%20null%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EFilters%20to%20be%20applied%20to%20the%20results.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EThe%20following%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3ECampaign%3C%2Fcode%3E%20fields%20are%20available%20for%20filtering%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3EexternalId%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20operators%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3EstartsWith%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3EnotStartsWith%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%3D%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E!%3D%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26lt%3B%26gt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26gt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26gt%3B%3D%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%3D%26gt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26lt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccode%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26lt%3B%3D%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%3D%26lt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3E%26lt%3B%3D%26gt%3B%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3EisNull%3C%2Fcode%3E%2C%20%3Ccode%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22prettyprint%22%3EisNotNull%3C%2Fcode%3E%3C%2Fli%3E
```

What's missing from my schema?

Comment: What is `MyAPI`? Your introspection result JSON should have only one property, and that's  `data`. How are you generating this introspection result?

Comment: @DanielRearden I had originally tried with the top level property being `data` and I've edited my question with what happens when I use that instead. The introspection result is generated by putting  this introspection query into my graphql client and copying the resulting json. https://gist.github.com/michiel/0cf0a76fb8714f6c9727be6f64256adf

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a syntax error, it's likely because the schema file is malformed. The easiest way to generate the introspection result for your endpoint is to just run this command:

```
apollo service:download --endpoint=<YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL>
```

This will generate a `schema.json` file in your working directory.

As a side note, in order to generate type definitions, you'll need client-side queries as well. Here's an [article that goes in to more detail](https://medium.com/open-graphql/automatically-generate-typescript-definitions-for-graphql-queries-with-apollo-codegen-e73eae72b561), since this is really outside the scope of your original question. Your complete command should look more like this:

```
apollo codegen:generate --localSchemaFile=schema.json --target=typescript --includes=src/**/*.ts --tagName=gql --addTypename --globalTypesFile=src/types/graphql-global-types.ts types
```

You can checkout [the docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output) for a description of all the options.

Answer (score 0):

This is my script:

```
{
    "types:generate": "apollo codegen:generate  --target=typescript --includes=src/**/*.ts --endpoint **youAPI** --header \"Authorization: Basic cHJvamVjdDpzZWV5b3V3ZWIyMDIw(replace your)\" --tagName=gql --addTypename --outputFlat src/types"
}
```

I hope it helps